# Logging in via AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I am having issues logging in via AJAX in my CodeIgniter solution.
The solution is an already existing code base and it uses community Auth library for the authentication part. 
I want the user to log in via AJAX and if successful have him logged in and redirected immediately to the previous page, if not successful, just show an error message.

I am frustrated after trying for 3+ hours to echo everything and try to debug it step by step.

This is the code I have so far.

My Back-end controller function:

```
public function logInWithAjax() {


        if( $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
        {
            // Allow this page to be an accepted login page
            $this->config->set_item('allowed_pages_for_login', ['backend/backend/logInWithAjax'] );

            // Make sure we aren't redirecting after a successful login
            $this->authentication->redirect_after_login = FALSE;

            // Do the login attempt
            $this->auth_data = $this->authentication->user_status( 0 );

            // Set user variables if successful login
            if( $this->auth_data )
                $this->_set_user_variables();

            // Call the post auth hook
            $this->post_auth_hook();

            // Login attempt was successful
            if( $this->auth_data )
            {
                echo json_encode([
                    'status'   => 1,
                    'user_id'  => $this->auth_user_id,
                    'username' => $this->auth_username,
                    'level'    => $this->auth_level,
                    'role'     => $this->auth_role,
                    'email'    => $this->auth_email
                ]);
            }

            // Login attempt not successful
            else
            {
                $this->tokens->name = 'login_token';

                $on_hold = (
                    $this->authentication->on_hold === TRUE OR
                    $this->authentication->current_hold_status()
                )
                    ? 1 : 0;

                echo json_encode([
                    'status'  => 0,
                    'count'   => $this->authentication->login_errors_count,
                    'on_hold' => $on_hold,
                    'token'   => $this->tokens->token()
                ]);
            }
        }

        // Show 404 if not AJAX
        else
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }
```

The problem is in the logInWithAjax function, it passes everything through fine in the user_status method up until the following line of code:

```
// Verify that the form token and flash session token are the same
            if( $this->CI->tokens->token_check( 'token', TRUE ) )
```

The result of this function is ALWAYS false regardless of anything. 
The function is the normal library code, i will paste it below.

```
/**
 * Check the token status with a provided token name, or "token" by default
 */
public function token_check( $rename = '', $dump_jar_on_match = FALSE )
{
    // If rename provided, check that token name
    $this->name = ( $rename == '' ) ? config_item('token_name') : $rename;

    // If no token jar contents, no reason to proceed
    if( ! empty( $this->jar ) )
    {
        // Set the posted_value variable
        if( $this->posted_value = $this->CI->input->post( $this->name ) )
        {
            // If the posted value matches one in the jar
            if( in_array( $this->posted_value, $this->jar ) )
            {
                // Successful token match !
                $this->match = TRUE;

                // Dump all tokens ?
                if( $dump_jar_on_match )
                {
                    $this->jar = [];

                    $this->save_tokens_cookie();
                }

                // Just delete the matching token
                else
                {
                    // What token jar key was the matching token ?
                    $matching_key = array_search( $this->posted_value, $this->jar );

                    // Remove the matching token from the jar
                    unset( $this->jar[ $matching_key ] );

                    // Auto generate a new token
                    $this->generate_form_token();
                }

                if( $this->debug )
                {
                    log_message( 'debug', count( $this->jar ) . '@token_check' );
                    log_message( 'debug', json_encode( $this->jar ) );
                }

                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I notice that the $this->match is put on TRUE correctly. Afterwards the value of $dump_jar_on_match is TRUE, as I pass literally that value. However, it refuses to go in IF clause when i put a return there to test, it doesn't return anything. The entire function keeps on returning false.

My login page is a simple form opening using form_open so the "token" hidden field is filled in.

```
<div class="card-content">
<div class="card-body">
    <?php
    echo form_open('', array('class' => 'form-horizontal loginform', 'id' => 'loginform', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate'));
    ?>
    <!--<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal loginform" action="#" novalidate="novalidate">-->
        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="user-name" name="login_string" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam of e-mail"
                   tabindex="1" required data-validation-required-message="Gelieve je gebruikersnaam of e-mail in te vullen aub.">
            <div class="form-control-position">
                <i class="ft-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="help-block font-small-3"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" name="login_pass" placeholder="Wachtwoord"
                   tabindex="2" required data-validation-required-message="Gelieve je wachtwoord in te vullen aub.">
            <div class="form-control-position">
                <i class="la la-key"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="help-block font-small-3"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <!--<div class="col-md-6 col-12 text-center text-md-left">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" class="chk-remember">
                    <label for="remember-me"> Remember Me</label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>-->
            <div class="col-md-12 col-12 text-center text-md-right"><a href="recover-password.html" class="card-link">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg login-button"><i class="ft-unlock"></i> Log in</button>
        <div class="hidden loader-wrapper login-ajax-loader">
            <div class="loader-container">
                <div class="ball-pulse-sync loader-green">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The JavaScript I have for now is:

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];

/*** START Log In Page JS ***/
//Login Register Validation
if($("form.loginform").attr("novalidate")!=undefined){
    $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({
        submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
            $('.login-button').addClass("hidden");
            $('.login-ajax-loader').removeClass("hidden");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + '/backend/backend/logInWithAjax',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //TODO: de ajax moet checken of de log in kan. Zoja -> redirect naar gewoon log in systeem (met redirect URL mee te geven)
                    //Zonee -> toon de error class stuff
                    if (!data.result) {
                        $('.login-page-alert').removeClass("hidden");
                    } else {
                        $('.login-page-alert').addClass("hidden");
                    }

                    //console.log($form.serialize());
                    //console.log('submitted successfully!');
                    //console.log(data);

                    $('.login-button').removeClass("hidden");
                    $('.login-ajax-loader').addClass("hidden");
                }
            });

            // will not trigger the default submission in favor of the ajax function
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are you getting a redirect in your ajax request? , what is the value of baseUrl in your javascript function? is it same as in your config? you can also use here your config baseurl as  `baseUrl ='<?=base_url()?>'`

Comment: Hello @DFriend , the jar is not empty/ I returned their values:
{"result":{"posted_value":"c0702485","jar":["e69a97eb","2748a0c6","b01dc1a4","d7d07cf5","c44a59c2","02de1f71","46e09544","5217cc8b","c0702485","92bec8dd"]}}

Comment: I am the author of Community Auth. I can tell you that the Tokens library is not your problem, and if it is it is because you don't have your cookies/sessions config set up correctly, or perhaps an issue with your PHP. Try turning on CodeIgniter logging to level 2, then try to log in and observe the debug lines that Community Auth adds to the log. Another thing to consider is that in the vast majority of cases of people having problems with Community Auth, the installation process was not understood or followed correctly. It doesn't look like that's the case here. Show posted data if possible!